# MATLAB Staying in bounds of Complex matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, complex-numbers

I have a complex matrix `cdata`, that is `2144x2048`. I am getting elements from `cdata` that are greater than a specified `threshold` by doing the following:

```
[row, col] = find(abs(cdata) > threshold);
```

`row` and `col` can have multiple values. Then, I take the row and col values, I perform a calculation to get N samples of the real x-data, and 33 samples of the y-data as follows:

```
xdata = real(cdata(row(i),col(i)-bw:col(i)+bw))
ydata = real(cdata(row(i)-bw:row(i)+bw,col(i)-bw:col(i)+bw))
```

where `bw` is a constant value that determines the number of samples I need to get. During this calculation, specifically the column portion of `cdata` for the `xdata` and the row portion of `cdata` for the `ydata`, I exceed the bounds of the matrix and MATLAB throws the following error:

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals
```

How can I ensure that I don't exceed the bounds? I'm ok with having to skip a row/col pair if it is going to exceed the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having problems is because you're not restricting your search to closer then `bw` from the edge of the matrix. This means its possible to find values above the threshold near the edges of the matrix. When you add or subtract `bw` from these indices you end up out of bounds. You can restrict your search like this.

```
[row, col] = find(abs(cdata(bw+1:end-bw,bw+1:end-bw)) > threshold);
row = row + bw;
col = col + bw;
```

This guarantees your row and column indices are within the bounds so when you grab a region surrounding them you won't go out of bounds.

On a side note. The `ydata` variable in your code is indexing an entire square region of the matrix and the `xdata` is only indexing a section of a row. Should your `ydata` actually be `ydata = real(cdata(row(i)-bw:row(i)+bw, col(i)))`?

Comment: great solution. And yes, you are right about the ydata, I mis-typed.